# rails 5 capybara test.log

Tags: testing, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm having trouble with a few test and I would like to see in `test.log` the requests there're being done. There's a config that I can change to register the requests in log like below?

```
Started GET "/carts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-25 19:09:55 -0300
  Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
  Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notice_modal.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (8.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alert_modal.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notice_modal.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 57.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.1, RSpec 3.6 and Capybara 2.14.4.

Thanks in advance for any help!

### Edit 1

I've the following config with capybara in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
require "capybara"
require "capybara/rspec"

....

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Comment: They should be showing up by default, unless you've changed your Capybara config to run tests against an instance other than the one Capybara starts up for testing.

Comment: Where is this config? I installed the gem and `require "capybara"` and 
`require "capybara/rspec"` inside `rails_helper.rb`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `require "capybara"`` but that's not affecting this.  Do you have anywhere else that you've specified `Capybara.<anything>` in your code?  Especially `Capybara.server_port` ?

Comment: I updated the question with any other `Capybara` config that I used, but there's nothing with `Capybara.server_port`.